# SSL SYSCALL error: Broken pipe

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, pdo

Currently experimenting with Laravel, trying to create a simple blog application with a Postgres database. I went ahead and configured the database and made sure that the PDO postgresql driver was installed, but when I run `php artisan migrate`, I get the following error:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] SSL SYSCALL error: Broken pipe
expected authentication request from server, but received S (SQL: select *
from information_schema.tables where table_schema = public and table_name = migrations)
```

This is then followed by a PDOException error that reads the same up until 'received S' and then ends.

Comment: Please post the PostgreSQL server version the version of `libpq` on the client side, the versions of the SSL libraries on both client and server and the connection string you are using.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand some of what you're asking for. This is all happening on one machine, so I don't understand what would constitute the 'client' in this case. I also don't know what you mean by 'connection string.' Where would that be?

Comment: Well, if database client and server ar on the same machine, they probably use the same database version. That is relevant information! You also didn't say in your question that client and server are on the same machine. The connection string is where you specify host, port, database name, user, password and others, like if you want SSL or not. The more information there is, the easier it is to make an educated guess or suggest experiments.